# Creating multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am looking to write a simple application to allow users to sort their dinner seating arrangements.

There are various categories and I am looking to use multidimensional array or arraylist to do the sorting.

For instance, the guest can be grouped into 3 levels:

**Affiliation**: Bride/ Groom side 
**Groups**: Family/ Friends/ Colleagues 
**Circles**: Workplace 1/ College Friends/ Neighbours etc

So, am I able to create an array as such:

Guests[**Affiliation**][**Groups**][**Circles**][*GuestID*].

So, if I do a count on the number of guests for Guests[**Groom**][**Friends**][**College**], it will display a *total X number of guests*.

Am I able to do just that?

Or is there any related reference that I can read/ refer to? I just can't seem to find the correct one or I may be searching in the wrong direction.  Please help.

Comment: I'd consider reorganising your array: `$guests = array(3 => array('name', => 'Mrs Henderson', 'affiliation' => 'groom', 'group' => 'family', 'circle' => 'mother'))` where the main index key (`3` in this case) is the guest ID. That should make it pretty easy to use `array_filter()` to make selections

Comment: I don't quite understand. Does that mean I have a 3-dimensional array nested inside an array list?

Comment: No, it's a 2 dimensional array that I'm suggesting (like an Excel spreadsheet): __you__ were suggesting a multi-dimensional array.... you'll find that 2d arrays are often easier to work with than 3- or 4-d arrays

Answer (score 0):

multidimensional array is very easy in php:

```
<?php
$Guests = array();

$Guests['Affiliation_1']['Groups_1']['Circles_1'] = array('GuestID_1', 'GuestID_2', 'GuestID_3');
$Guests['Affiliation_2']['Groups_2']['Circles_2'] = array('GuestID_4', 'GuestID_5');
$Guests['Affiliation_3']['Groups_3']['Circles_3'] = array('GuestID_6', 'GuestID_7', 'GuestID_8', 'GuestID_9');

echo count($Guests['Affiliation_1']['Groups_1']['Circles_1']); //output is 3
echo count($Guests['Affiliation_2']['Groups_2']['Circles_2']); //output is 2
echo count($Guests['Affiliation_3']['Groups_3']['Circles_3']); //output is 4


$Guests['Affiliation_3']['Groups_1']['Circles_2'] = array('GuestID_10', 'GuestID_11', 'GuestID_12');
echo count($Guests['Affiliation_3']['Groups_1']['Circles_2']); //output is 3

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go try it out in a while!